# How to find weekends inside a date array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, find, getdate

I have a date array, what I want is to do two things with it.

1.- Tell me how many dates within it are weekends
2.- Create a new arrangement with the dates that are weekends

I tried the following code but I don't know how to return when the weekend is true, as you can see the code only evaluates when getDay is 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday), I would have to find a way to put those that are true inside the array

```js
const attendanceDates = [
  "2022-11-21",
  "2022-11-22",
  "2022-11-24",
  "2022-11-26"
]

const whenIsWeekend = [];
attendanceDates.forEach(element => {

  const date = new Date(element)
  var dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();
  var isWeekend = (dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0); // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
  console.log('isWeekend', isWeekend);
  if (isWeekend) {
    whenIsWeekend.push(element)
  }
})


console.log('array of Weekend', whenIsWeekend)

console.log('count weekends', whenIsWeekend.length)
```

What I hope to return

```
array of Weekend [
   "2022-11-26"
]
count weekends 1
```

Thank your in advance

Comment: Am I missing something, your code already returns what you *said* you are expecting it to return?

Comment: I'm a little confused because your code works. The only issue seems to be with time zones as your `whenIsWeekend` array can return the wrong day depending on the user's timezone. But that can easily be fixed by using `.getUTCDay()` instead of `.getDay()`

Comment: It is that it is returning the day "2022-11-21" and it should not be like that, because the date 21 is not a weekend day within the arrangement, the weekend is 2022-11-26, that would be he evaluated to "6" with getDay so that's why I'm confused by the behavior

Comment: @Izlia Using `.getUTCDay()` fixes that issue. Also you should probably be using `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`. Typically you only use map to modify an array, but in this case you are just looping through it and adding values to a separate array.

Comment: Yes! That is all! I did not know that the time zone could be affected. Managing dates is a headache for me, thank you, and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the native Javascript date object:

```
const attendanceDates = [
  "2022-11-21",
  "2022-11-22",
  "2022-11-24",
  "2022-11-26"
]

const weekends = attendanceDates.filter(date => {
    const dateObj = new Date(date)
    const dayOfWeek = dateObj.getUTCDay();

    if (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) {
        return true;
    }
})

console.log(weekends) //["2022-11-26"]
```

Using moment.js library (ideal if you need to do many date manipulations easily)

```
const attendanceDates = [
  "2022-11-21",
  "2022-11-22",
  "2022-11-24",
  "2022-11-26"
]

const weekends = attendanceDates.filter(date => {
    const dateMoment = moment(date)
    if (dateMoment.day() == 0 || dateMoment.day() == 6) {
        return true;
    }
})

console.log(weekends) //["2022-11-26"]
```

Comment: Perfect! That's all, thank you! I did not know that the time zone could cause problems when doing the tour and there was my mistake